# Assume two llvm::Values*s in different functions are equal

Tags: optimization, llvm, constants

I have two LLVM functions that use an API.  Something like this:

```
define void @funcA() {
  ...
  call void @api_set(i32 %someValue)
  ...
}

define void @funcB() {
  ...
  %sameValue = call i32 @api_get()
  ...
}

declare void @api_set(i32)

declare i32 @api_get()
```

The functions `api_set` and `api_get` are black boxes to the optimizer.

However, I know that for these particular calls, `%someValue` in `funcA` will always be equal to `%sameValue` in `funcB`.

When LLVM optimizes these functions, the constant propagation pass may find that `%someValue` can be replaced with a constant.  Is there a way to tell LLVM it is allowed to also replace `%sameValue` when it replaces `%someValue`?  Perhaps an attribute/metadata/etc?  Something simpler that I'm missing?

I have already made a pass that checks for this, and it works, but the pass has such a simple specification that I imagine there is a simpler/more lightweight way to achieve this.

P.S. If there is a way to do this in C that would be helpful too.

Comment: So, you basically want to explain to the optimizer that after calling `api_set(<something>)` the `api_get()` would return that `<something>`?

Comment: Yes.  Feel free to edit the question if it's not clear.  In this case is also safe to assume that api_set is called before api_get